# Cygwin and WinPcap 4.1.3 timestamp - microsecond issue - header->ts.tv_usec not correct - C program

Tags: c, timestamp, cygwin, winpcap

I am working on developing a customized packet sniffer for Windows 7 64 bit host system (NIC card is Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller) and am using WinPcap 4.3.1 library using C programming and Cygwin development platform. I am able to read outgoing and incoming TCP and UDP packets through my program. However, I am stuck in a problem of not able to get correct timestamp in microsecond from the **struct pcap_pkthdr** structure. Following is the code snippet from the program where the problem exists:

```
... 

int getPacket; 
struct pcap_pkthdr *header;  
const u_char *pkt_data;  

/* Sniff the packets */  
while((getPacket= pcap_next_ex(handle, &header, &pkt_data)) >= 0)   
{      

printf("\n 1) Epoch is: %ld",header->ts.tv_sec&0x00000000ffffffff);     

printf("\n 2) Microsecond is:  %ld",header->ts.tv_usec);   

...
```

Following is the **console output** that I got for these 2 printf() statements in a run:

1) Epoch is: 1460262399
2) Microsecond is: 1576252997999

Time in seconds (header->ts.tv_sec&0x00000000ffffffff) is correct as it translates to 2016-04-09::23:26:39 (**yy-mm-dd::hh-mm-ss** format)

However, the Microsecond (header->ts.tv_usec) is not correct as the hex value of Microsecond is **0x16F0000016F** that always shows this kind of repeating pattern (with different values) at the low and high octet positions. I have analyzed memory dumps and found the same values that makes me believe that the **header->ts.tv_usec** is not filled correctly by the NPF driver.

I did a lot of search and could not find this issue reported anywhere. Also, I tested the code on separate AMD and Intel machines and the issue seems to linger.

Any suggestion(s) to solve this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: All the bits of `tv_sec` are significant, so you shouldn't be ANDing it with `0x00000000ffffffff`.  What happens if you just do `printf("\n 1) Epoch is: %ld",header->ts.tv_sec);`?

Comment: Thanks Guy. In fact, I showed ANDing with `0x00000000ffffffff` to highlight the fact that only 32 lower significant bits of tv_sec are valid. In my code, I typecast it with (int).  `printf("\n 1) Epoch is: %ld",header->ts.tv_sec)` results in full 64 bit number e.g. `1341397056348719 (0x4C3FE570BE22F)`. You can see that only last 8 octets are meaningful. I found it through test and trials.

Comment: "highlight the fact that only 32 lower significant bits of tv_sec are valid"  If that's a fact, that's a *bug* in WinPcap!  We'd like WinPcap to continue to run in 2038 and later, at least on 64-bit platforms, and that requires that all 64 bits of tv_sec be valid, and we'd like it to be compatible with UN\*X libpcap, on which all 64 bits are significant.  There might be *another* bug in 64-bit WinPcap causing the problems you're seeing.

Comment: Or perhaps this is a problem with Cygwin.  What happens if you do `printf("size and offset of tv_sec: %u, %u\n", (unsigned int)sizeof(header->ts.tv_sec), (unsigned int)offsetof(struct pcap_pkthdr, ts.tv_sec));` and `printf("size and offset of tv_usec: %u, %u\n", (unsigned int)sizeof(header->ts.tv_usec), (unsigned int)offsetof(struct pcap_pkthdr, ts.tv_usec));`

Comment: @Guy Harris  
Following is the result of the above 2 printf();  
  
**size and offset of tv_sec:  8, 0**  
**size and offset of tv_usec:  8, 8**

Comment: Nope, that's not going to work; WinPcap expects them to match the Microsoft definition, in which case tv_sec's size and offset would be 4 and 0, and tv_usec's offset would be 4 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in WinPcap, there *are* only 32 bits in `tv_sec`.

WinPcap uses [Microsoft's definition of `struct timeval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740560(v=vs.85).aspx) - it does not require Cygwin, so it can't use Cygwin's definition - and, in that definition, `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` are both `long`, and, in MSVC, `long` is 32-bit *even on 64-bit platforms*.  (You need a different data type for a 64-bit integer.)

From your test, Cygwin's `struct timeval` has a 64-bit `tv_sec` and a 64-bit `tv_usec` on 64-bit platforms.  Therefore:

1. Cygwin *will not work* with WinPcap on 64-bit platforms;
2. a 64-bit Cygwin program using WinPcap will think that the seconds and microseconds fields of a pcap time stamp are a 64-bit `tv_sec` field, so only the lower 32 bits will be valid, and will think that some random locations in memory are the `tv_usec` field, so you'll see the behavior that you're reporting.

Comment: Thanks for the details. They are quite helpful in reducing the scope of the problem. I have tried to modify the machine.h file of Cygwin where the structures TIME_T and __suseconds_t are changed from LONG to unsigned int. But it has an effect of stopping the printf() function from console output (only the printf() that has time structures). Program runs without any coredump and finishes without any error. Is it the same issue where you mentioned that program will jump to random memory locations and thus gets terminated without reporting any error?

Comment: "you mentioned that program will jump to random memory locations" No, I didn't.  I said "a 64-bit Cygwin program using WinPcap ... will think that some random locations in memory are the `tv_usec` field", i.e. that it will reference some "random locations in memory" as *data*, not as *code*.  The locations aren't "random" in the sense of having random memory addresses - their addresses are right after what `header` points to - but what that corresponds to *is* random, with no guarantee of what's there.

Comment: "I have tried to modify the machine.h file of Cygwin where the structures TIME_T and __suseconds_t are changed from LONG to unsigned int."  I cannot guarantee what other effects, probably undesirable effects, this will have on any code you compile that directly or directly includes that header; that might break all sorts of other things in your code.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot Guy Haris. It was quite helpful. I found out at [link](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-04/msg00376.html) that **LONG** data types compatibility is an issue with Cygwin at Windows due to **LLP64** in Windows/MinGW vs. **LP64** in Linux/Cygwin. Seems like the only option I have is to switch to MinGW compiler. However, before I step into this, just want to know if there is any safe workaround for this issue (I could not find it reported anywhere). I mean to say if there is any way, where we can read **LONG** of Windows (4 bytes) in Cygwin (8 bytes LONG) safely?

Comment: Yes, MinGW is GCC-for-Windows, Cygwin is UN\*X-like-environment-for-Windows, so, in 64-bit environments, the first uses Microsoft's 32-bit `long` and the second uses UN\*X-like systems' 64-bit `long`.  What WinPcap gives you has 32-bit `tv_sec` and `tv_usec`, so the *ONLY* safe way to access it is in that fashion; to use it with Cygwin, you'll need to define a structure with 32-bit seconds and microseconds, cast `&header->ts` from `struct timeval *` to a pointer to that structure type, and dereference the resulting pointer.

Comment: Added a prototype of **timeval32** structure in main program file with **unsigned INT** data types for seconds and microsecond. It seems to work after I typecast the original **timeval** with **timeval32** structure pointer. I can validate the seconds using EPOCH counter. However, in order to validate the microsecond values, I used **gettimeofday()** function. Using the same technique (with a separate variable), I am getting 0 value for microsecond while second is ok. Moreover, **gettimeofday()** function is printing correct values when I use normal **timeval** structure. Did I miss something?

Comment: You are passing a `struct timeval`, not a `struct timeval32`, to `gettimeofday()`, right?  If not, do so; you ***CANNOT*** pass a Win32-style always-32-bit `struct timeval`, which is what your `struct timeval32` is, to a Cygwin routine that expects a 64-bit `struct timeval`.

Comment: True, I am passing `struct timeval`. However, afterwards, I do the same typecasting that I did for `struct timeval32` to validate if the structure is getting correct microsecond. Although `gettimeofday()` uses same 64 bit 'struct timeval' as used by `struct pcap_pkthdr`, but it does not seem to be affected by the same issue as happened with  `struct pcap_pkthdr` and when I use typecasting, microsecond field is 0. Is it something to do with the internal functionality of `gettimeofday()`?

Comment: If you are calling a Cygwin routine such as `gettimeofday()`, it expects to be passed (or passed a pointer to) a `struct timeval` with the Cygwin layout, which means a 64-bit `tv_sec` and a 64-bit `tv_usec`.  *You cannot take a `struct timeval` with the MSVC/Windows layout, which means a 32-bit `tv_sec` and a 32-bit `tv_usec`, and cast that pointer to `struct timeval *` and expect it to work.  Furthermore, you cannot do that case and use it to look at the `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` in that structure.  You must treat `struct timeval` and `struct timeval32` as different data types.*

Comment: "Although `gettimeofday()` uses same 64 bit 'struct timeval' as used by `struct pcap_pkthdr`"  No, it does ***NOT***.   `gettimeofday()` is a Cygwin routine, and uses, on a 64-bit platform, a 64-bit `struct timeval`.  `struct pcap_pkthdr` is a WinPcap structure, designed to be used with the Windows `struct timeval`, which is a *32-bit* `struct timeval`.  They use *different* structures, and must be handled differently.

Comment: Haris. Thanks. I think my code is pretty stable now.